# Having trouble with Nested-Objects using Nest

Tags: dictionary, elasticsearch, nest

When I try to index a doc of my defined type, having a list which is supposed to be mapped as a nested-object ("type":"nested"), it's getting mapped as a regular object type.

Take a look at the code:

I've got a simple class like this one:

```
[ElasticType()]
public class MyJob
{
    [ValueFieldAttribute]
    public int jobCode { get; set; }

    [ValueFieldAttribute(Type = FieldType.nested)]
    public IList<JobProfessionalFieldInfo> JobProfessionalFields { get; set; }
}
```

The code for the JobProfessionalFieldInfo class is:

```
[ElasticType()]
public class JobProfessionalFieldInfo
{
    [ValueFieldAttribute]
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    [ValueFieldAttribute]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

The code for the ValueFieldAttribute class is:

```
public class ValueFieldAttribute : ElasticPropertyAttribute
{
    public ValueFieldAttribute()
        : base()
    {
        this.Store = false;
        this.Index = FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed;
    }
}
```

My program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConnectionSettings node = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        node.SetDefaultIndex("jobs");
        ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(node);

        List<JobProfessionalFieldInfo> list = new List<JobProfessionalFieldInfo>();
        list.Add(new JobProfessionalFieldInfo { CategoryId = 1, JobId = 1 });
        list.Add(new JobProfessionalFieldInfo { CategoryId = 2, JobId = 2 });
        var res = client.Index<MyJob>(new MyJob
        {
            jobCode = 1,
            JobProfessionalFields = list
        },"jobs", "MyJob",1);
    }
```

Now, when I run it, it indexes the object successfully... BUT(!!) when I get the mapping of the index with GET jobs/MyJob/_mapping, I see that jobProfessionalFields has no "type":"nested" in its mapping.

That results in a query like the following one, returning the indexed doc while it's not supposed to get it back (that's what nested-type is for right?..):

```
GET jobs/_search
{
    "query": 
    {
        "bool": 
        {
            "must": 
            [
               {"match": {"jobId":1}},
               {"match": {"categoryId":2}}               
            ]
        }
    }    
}
```

It's not the end:
I'd a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218346/facet-on-nested-field-with-elasticsearch-c-sharp-mpdreamz-nest-client),
there the guy that answered tells that when we use annotations we need to manually call the createIndex and Map methods, but the problem is that I don't have any generic Map method...!
Take a look at [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/26606120/): (just to make you get into the link - here's its start..)

```
namespace Nest
{
    public partial class ElasticClient...
```

And I don't know how to use the non-generic Map  method to put the mapping of my MyJob class.

How can I cause this stuff to map the jobProfessionalFields as nested-type dudes?

Thanks for any help of you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it LOL!

The MapFromAttributes<> is the right generic method for putting the mapping (at least in the current Nest version I'm using - 0.12.0).
But it demands a manual call for the index creationg, o.w it gives an IndexMissing exception (like the guy in the above mentioned link said).

```
        client.CreateIndex("jobs", new IndexSettings { });
        var res = client.MapFromAttributes<MyJob>("jobs","MyJob");
```

But that's really interesting why isn't it enough to just define the

[ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.nested)],

in order to get the nested mapping though..

I would be glad to get an answer for that one.